# Prohibit reading from /dev/tty

Tags: python, linux, terminal, subprocess

Tools like `sudo` read from /dev/tty to read a password.

I would like to avoid this.

The subprocess should not be able to read /dev/tty. The subprocess should fail immediately instead of waiting for input for ever.

I am using the `subprocess` module of Python. The subprocess should fail if it tries to read from /dev/tty.

Remember: The tool `sudo` is just an example. A fancy command line argument to sudo does not solve my problem. This should work for all linux command line tools.

Question: How to make any tool fail as soon as it wants to read from /dev/tty (called via the subprocess module of Python)?

Background: This is a normal linux user process, not root.

Comment: What is your question? How to remove read permissions from `/dev/tty`, or what?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs I updated the question.

Comment: Maybe [`start_new_session=True`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) when creating the process does what you need?

Comment: @mata thank you this works! Please write `start_new_session=True` as answer, I will upvote and accept it.

Comment: In the specific case of `sudo`, you probably just want the `-n` switch to put sudo into non-interactive mode.

Comment: @DanielPryden Remember: The tool sudo is just an example. A fancy command line argument to sudo does not solve my problem. This should work for all linux command line tools.

Comment: @guettli: That's fine, but the common pattern is that tools that would try to read from alternative inputs will normally have an argument to control that behavior. More generally: a program with `setuid` powers can technically read or write from any tty device on the system, regardless of which one its session is attached to (if any), so you couldn't *stop* sudo from reading from e.g. `/dev/ttyS01` if it wanted to (unless you ran it in a chroot, but even that isn't 100% secure).

Comment: @guettli: It sounds like your actual desire here is: you want to launch a command-line program and guarantee that it won't block for user input. That is actually an impossible task (literally, it's the halting problem). You can detach most of the common routes by which it could try to interact with the user, but that's just a convenience, not a security measure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since python3.2 [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) takes an argument `start_new_session` which will cause the executed process to be started detached from the current controlling terminal by calling `setsid()` prior to executing the child process.

So all you should need is to start the process with `start_new_session=True`

Comment: Thank you very much. The new version of subx uses this by default: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/subx/